# how to put a p at the center of a div?

Tags: html, css, styles, padding, text-align

I have a popup window and I have 2 `<p>` within a `<div>`
the div has `padding-left` & `padding-right` and I want to put the `p` tags in the center of the div. how should I do it?

here is the code:

```
<div class="sign"><p class="sign_text"> ' + sign + '</p> <p class="sign_text"> ' + this.sender + '</p> <div>
```

the style

```
'.sign{padding-left: ' + this.sign_padding_left + ';' +
  'padding-right: ' + this.sign_padding_right + ' +; font-family: IRANSharp;}' + 
  '.sign_text{margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center}</style>'
```

[image: this is what I want, but it shouldn't be in the center of the page, I want this part to have left and right paddings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css

```
.sign{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; // align horizontally center
  aligns-items: center;  // align vertically center
}
```

Edit 1: Based on the image you have added

```
.sign{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 80%; /*Change this for left adjustment*/
}
```

Comment: but I put the div at the center of the page, I want to have special paddings but the p tags are not centered under each other

Comment: Can you elaborate more and create a working plunker?

Comment: I added an image, I want two texts to be like that but not at the center of the page, I want them to have left padding from the page

Comment: add padding-left to .sign. Change `justify-content: center;` to `justify-content: flex-start;`  Hope this is what you expecting.

Comment: still not working

Comment: I have updated the answer based on the image you have added.

Comment: yes it works with adding width but i did it with a table and it works

Answer (score 0):

This to me is a great use for flexbox.

Try something like this:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p { // use a class obviously
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is a great resource for flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Just add { display: block; } to .sign class then text-align will work.